# TCP Listener / Proxy in C#

Tags: c#, tcp, tcplistener, httplistener

I have several machines running an application that plays a video feed from a camera. Each machine is located behind a firewall on different LANs.  I am trying to investigate an approach to be able to talk to these machines from an Azure web app and get access to the video they are streaming.  I don't want to have to open ports on any LAN.  My first attempt at this was to have a client  running on each machine that contacts an intermediate Azure service via a TCP port, the port is kept open and the local machine sends data to the Azure service which basically downloads this data and then sends it on to any connected clients.

The problem I am having is the intermediate service essentially has to download each message and then retransmit it to any clients, I don't think this approach will scale as the intermediate server can become overrun very easily.  Ideally all I would like the intermediate service to do is manage the connections between the local machines and the end client azure service so that they talk directly to one and other.

I guess this must be similar to what products like TeamViewer or LogMeIn do.

I'd appreciate any pointers or suggestions from others experience.

Comment: If you want to mediate a peer-to-peer network, you need to start looking into NAT hole punching to get the clients to be able to connect to each other from behind routers. There are libraries and tools for this. It can be said that it's somewhat of an art, rather than a science.

Comment: If clients connect to server, hole punch isnt needed.

Comment: Hole punching never will connect if target port is closed .

Comment: I've never used it and I'm sure it's not free, but have you considered using any of the azure options? Like https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/media-services/ or https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/learning-paths/media-services-streaming-live/?

Comment: Fair point poida, my biggest concern is the cost, this really is a small scale solution I'm trying to implement.  The cost of live streaming from Azure is quite expensive for my needs even if I could get it to work with my current infrastructure

Comment: Where you say "the intermediate service essentially has to download each message and then retransmit it to any clients", could the intermediary put the data into an azure storage account then generate and forward the clients a download link?

Comment: No, this is for real time video streaming, the client app is ultimately using the HTML video tag to stream